# Defer TabPanel rendering sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on a big application, with tabpanel containing 5 tabs.

I would like to defer the render of the not active first tab, to speed up the loading of the application.

I've seen on Ext JS that there is an attribute deferRender, but it does not exist in sencha touch.

Problems is that sencha load all the image in the others panel causing delay in loading.

Someboy know any fix ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question: [items not loading in sencha touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311063/items-not-loading-in-sencha-touch-2)

I made the following fiddle. Take a look, it briefly shows how it might be done: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/k2j

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm a little bit afraid of painted listeners, as it is thrown randomly in some devices (cause to load the memory on iPhone by example).

Comment: I used your answer with android, gained some seconds at loading, will try with iPhone. Thank You !